# Missing dependencies in package.json while creating React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I have created App using create-react-app and npx create-react-app my-app,create-react-app my-app --use-npm and many other possible options available on the internet. But i am getting the below message after project creation "Missing dependencies in package.json"  and when i try to start the app using npm start entering the app folder i get the below error.

D:\ReactNative\ReactApplication\my-app1>npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Contents of the Package.json file created in App folder is as mentioned below

{
  "name": "my-app1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true
 }

Do let me know how to make React work on my System

System and other details mentioned below.
OS: Windows10
Node: v12.14.0
npm: 6.13.4

Regards,
Nitesh

Comment: can you post the pull packege.json file?

Comment: the package.json content is alraedy shown for app my-app1.   { "name": "my-app1", "version": "0.1.0", "private": true }

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the old project folder and install a new one.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

**OR** run below command in the project directory, because the app isn't installed completely. Recommended to Install new like above example

```
npm install
```

Comment: First part already tried, output of 2nd part is PS D:\ReactNative\ReactApplication\my-app1> npm install
up to date in 0.148s

Answer (score 0):

Delete C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming next npm-cache and npm, reinstall and create scaffold to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I tried from many days but this issue not resolved !

I think there is problems in npm so i download yarn
Step 1: Install Yarn from the official website.

Step 2: Check the Yarn version using yarn -v.

Step 3: To create a new React project, run the following command:

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Replace my-app with your desired project name.

**Starting the Project:**
To start the project, use the following command:

```
yarn start
```

**Building the Project:**
To build the project for production, use the following command:

```
yarn build
```

**Ejecting the Project:**
If you want to eject the project, use the following command:

```
yarn eject
```

**Additional Information:** For more details and documentation, you can refer to the following link: Create React App GitHub Repository

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35718144)